# GSM shield SIM card troubles

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm, shields

So I'm trying to use the GSM shield to communicate with my smart phone. The SIM card that came with the shield only works with other devices on that network, and it's an obscure latin network that I don't have so I cant use that one, and I bought another t-mobile SIM card activation kit, but I can't figure out how to activate it without having an actual T-mobile number. Somebody please help me! Either help me figure out a way to get the T-mobile SIM card to work or tell me what other SIM to use! If you used the GSM shield with a different SIM card, could you give me a link to where you bought it? Thanks!

Comment: How do you propose to use the GSM shield to communicate with your smart phone? SMS?

Comment: Yeah, I was going to use SMS.